# Inserting a vertical line between radio button/answer choices

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm having trouble inserting a vertical line between the second to last radio button and the last one. Basically to separate the last choice in the likert scale and the "i don't know" option. Can anyone else help please?

[Heres's what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzwvX.png)

Here's a code I found to hide a radio button (another option I am open to to hide a radio button between the two choice to create "whitespace")

```
$('QR~QID154~198').up().hide();
```

It didn't seem to work...maybe I have to specify which answer choice? Any advice can help as I am not a programmer at all. It's just Qualtrics doesn't have the feature to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I am using Javascript

Comment: it's hard to suggest anything without the html markup of the radio buttons (in Chrome you can right-click the radio buttons and select Inspect to copy-paste the relevant parts of the html in your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following. You can adjust the style to meet your needs.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $(this.questionId).down('.ChoiceStructure').select('td').last().style.borderLeft = "3px solid grey";
});
```

P.S. Are you the person who left a comment on the marketinview/Qualtrics_MatrixVerticalLineBeforeLastColumn.js gist a couple of days ago?  I don't get notified nor check comments there.

Comment: T. Gibbons, YES! Haha. Thank you! I just asked another qualtrics question. Is it too selfish for me to ask you to look at that and help me? If not, it's okay too. :)